# Why function calculate distance between 2 element not work when call by ajax post requests?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why function calculate distance between 2 element not work when call by ajax post requests ?

When i load page `index.php` , function calculate distance between 2 element not work.

But when i load page `test.php` , function calculate distance between 2 element work good.

How to edit code for function calculate distance between 2 element work good when load page `index.php`  ?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySpan').hide();
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#f1id').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySpan').show();
                    $('#mySpan').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
});
</script>
</head>

<form name="f1" id="f1id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value=""/>
</form>
<span id="mySpan" style=" float: left; "></span>
```

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
    font: 11px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;    
}
#ref_box1 {
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
}
#element_bottom{   
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 2px;    
    /* margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; */
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#distance_bottom1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
(function() {
    var btm = $('#element_bottom'),
        ref = $('#ref_box1'),
        refTop = ref.position().top,
        btmTop = btm.position().top;       
    $('#distance_bottom1 span').text(Math.abs(refTop-btmTop));    
    window.distance_bottom1 = Math.abs(refTop-btmTop);    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       btmTop = btm.position().top;        
       window.distance_bottom1 = Math.abs(refTop-btmTop);
       $('#distance_bottom1 span').text(Math.abs(refTop-btmTop));    
    });    
})();
});
</script>



<p id="distance_bottom1">distance 1: <span>0</span>px</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>   
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<span id="ref_box1"></span>     
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="element_bottom"></div>
```

Comment: window.load fired before you add script that uses window.load

Comment: @ epascarello How can i do please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no window load event when you are using ajax to post to a php page. Just take out the window.load event and it should work fine.

remove:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
```

and

```
 });
```

Comment: but when i load page index.php , and scroll page value distance not change real time.